# zip all files and subfolder in directory without parent directory

Tags: directory, filenames, zip

I have the following folder structure

```
folder
|
|--foo.txt
|
|--sub_folder
   |
   |--bar.txt
```

I want to zip the content (files and sub folders) of folder without including the root folder in the zip.

I have tried command

`zip -r package.zip folder`

But this includes the root folder. Also tried the following form

`zip -j -r package.zip folder`

But this will flatten all the directory structures and just include the files. How do I preserve the internal directory structure but ignore the parent folder?

Answer (score 35, accepted):

`zip` stores paths relative to the current directory (when it is invoked), so you need to change that:

```
(cd folder && zip -r "$OLDPWD/package.zip" .)
```

`&&` ensures that `zip` only runs if the directory was correctly changed, and the parentheses run everything in a subshell, so the current directory is restored at the end. Using `OLDPWD` avoids having to calculate the relative path to `package.zip`.

Answer (score 2):

```
zip -r package.zip folder/*
```

The above command will zip all files and sub folders under `folder` directory (It will ignore the parent directory for folder)

Comment: This will store the `folder/` path in the archive, which the OP doesn’t want. It will also ignore any hidden files inside `folder`.

Answer (score 1):

To add to other answers, for scripts, you could use

```sh
pushd folder; zip -r ../package.zip .; popd
```

`pushd` changes the directory much like `cd`, but remembers the previous one, and `popd` restores the last remembered directory.

In this case it's equivalent to removing the parentheses (which spawn a new shell) and adding `; cd ..` at the end of the command suggested by Stephen.

Note: I would add this as a comment, but I can't because I do not have enough reputation.

Comment: Stephen’s answer is fine as it is; it doesn’t need anything added to it.  Do you believe that your approach is *better* than his?  Why?  … … … … … … … … … … … … … … … … … … Please do not respond in comments; [edit] your answer to make it clearer and more complete.

Comment: It's a nice trick that is useful especially when writing *scripts* as I mentioned in the first sentence.

Comment: It's not necessarily better, but can make your life easier. For example, if you go a few directories down but need to back later in the script, it's easier to just `popd` than to `cd ../../../../`. It's easy to get the number of levels you have to go up wrong. Can't make that mistake with `popd` though. 

Thanks for coming to my speech inside a comment!

Comment: Well, my point is that you don’t seem to fully understand Stephen’s answer.  He is using parentheses, not as English punctuation, but as shell syntax, causing the commands within the parentheses to run in a subshell.  So the `cd` changes the working directory *of the subshell* but not the main shell.  To borrow your language, the main shell process *remembers* what directory it is in, by *staying there*; it’s still there when the subshell terminates, so nothing needs to be *restored.* … (Cont’d)

Comment: (Cont’d) …  If Stephen’s answer is a line in a script, the command on the next line (or even after a `;`) is executed in the directory above “`folder`”.  You can try this yourself with ``(pwd; cd /; pwd); pwd`` (from the command line ***or*** in a script).  That’s why I said “Stephen’s answer is fine as it is; it doesn’t need anything added to it.” — it doesn’t need to **`cd ..`**.

Comment: Thanks, you're right, I didn't know about the shell spawning. Looks like Stephen's answer  would benefit from the parentheses syntax explanation. I still do not think that it hurts to leave my answer hanging here at the bottom.

Comment: I’ve added an explanation to my answer, thanks for the suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `-j` or `--junk-paths` in the command to avoid parent directory and zip only the file.
[Zip command reference](https://linux.die.net/man/1/zip)

> `-j`
> `--junk-paths`
>
> Store just the name of a saved file (junk the path), and do not store directory
> names. By default, `zip` will store the full path (relative to the current
> directory).

[Reference of the answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/940754/960385)

Comment: This flattens all the subfolders too which is not what the op wanted. Your output will contain the foo.txt and bar.txt files without the subfolder.